# How to print a specific line of all files in a directory?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I ran into an error saying line 235 of my Makefile has error:

```
make[4]: Leaving directory `/opt/home/root/native-upstream/native_client/tools/SRC/glibc/wctype'
make  subdir=manual -C manual ..=../ subdir_lib
make[4]: Entering directory `/opt/home/root/native-upstream/native_client/tools/SRC/glibc/manual'
Makefile:235: *** mixed implicit and normal rules.  Stop.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/opt/home/root/native-upstream/native_client/tools/SRC/glibc/manual'
make[3]: *** [manual/subdir_lib] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/home/root/native-upstream/native_client/tools/SRC/glibc'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/home/root/native-upstream/native_client/tools/BUILD/build-glibc32'
make[1]: *** [BUILD/stamp-glibc32] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/home/root/native-upstream/native_client/tools'
make: *** [build-with-glibc] Error 2
```

But I don't know which Makefile has this error, there are tons of Makefiles in my project:

```
#  find . -name Makefile
./tools/Makefile
./tools/BUILD/.gcc-extra-build-cloog-ppl/doc/Makefile
./tools/BUILD/.gcc-extra-build-cloog-ppl/Makefile
./tools/BUILD/.gcc-extra-build-cloog-ppl/test/Makefile
./tools/BUILD/.gcc-extra-build-gmp/printf/Makefile
./tools/BUILD/.gcc-extra-build-gmp/doc/Makefile
./tools/BUILD/.gcc-extra-build-gmp/tests/Makefile
./tools/BUILD/.gcc-extra-build-gmp/tests/devel/Makefile
...
```

So I would like to print line 235 of each Makefile to find out who is the culprit, something like:

```
./tools/Makefile: 235: $(objpfx)c++-types-check.out: $(check-data) scripts/check-c++-types.sh
./tools/BUILD/.gcc-extra-build-cloog-ppl/doc/Makefile: 235: ifneq (,$(check-data))
./tools/BUILD/.gcc-extra-build-cloog-ppl/Makefile: 235: $(objpfx)c++-types-check.out:
./tools/BUILD/.gcc-extra-build-cloog-ppl/test/Makefile: 235: endif
./tools/BUILD/.gcc-extra-build-gmp/printf/Makefile: 235:
./tools/BUILD/.gcc-extra-build-gmp/doc/Makefile: 235:
./tools/BUILD/.gcc-extra-build-gmp/tests/Makefile: 235: #   Master Makefile for the GNU C library
./tools/BUILD/.gcc-extra-build-gmp/tests/devel/Makefile: 235:
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I've never seen a build script where you couldn't *see* which script or makefile was being called, and which one failed.  Are you *sure* you need to hunt down "line 235" in all your makefiles???

Comment: @paulsm4 Updated my question. I'm not familiar with Makefile, do you know how to locate which Makefile it is by this output?

Comment: Yup.  As Brian Campbell said below, the culprit is the "Makefile" in `/opt/home/root/native-upstream/native_client/tools/SRC/glibc/manual`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the problem is in `/opt/home/root/native-upstream/native_client/tools/SRC/glibc/manual/Makefile`, given that the line immediately before the error says it's entering that directory:

```
make[4]: Entering directory `/opt/home/root/native-upstream/native_client/tools/SRC/glibc/manual'
Makefile:235: *** mixed implicit and normal rules.  Stop.
```

That said, there are a few ways you could find line 235 of each Makefile. People have already pointed out awk and sed solutions. If you want the filename as well, a quick and easy solution is to use `grep`:

```
find . -name Makefile -print0 | xargs -0 grep -nH $ | grep :235:
```

The find command finds all files named Makefile, printing them out null-delimited (so that you don't have problems if there are files with spaces in their names). `xargs` passes those filenames to `grep`. `grep -nH` prints the filename and line number for every matching line; the `$` as the pattern ensures that every line matches (it matches the end of each line). Then you grep within that for the line number you're looking for.

It's not perfect; you might find a few lines that happen to contain ":235:" in them, but it should be fine for a quick one-off (if you really care, you could use `grep '^[^:]*:235:' to ensure that you only match the line number).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the Makefile for me, and the output of the command is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the most straightforward way would be

```
sed -n '235p' *
```

That would print line 235 of all the files in the current directory. If you want to recurse through directories, or exclude certain files, you'll have to use a more explicit glob or `find` with `-exec`.

So in the end, what you probably want is this:

```
find . -type f -name Makefile -print -exec sed -n '235p' {} \;
```

Comment: I think maybe he need an automatic way, `235` may change?

Comment: Tried and but it only checks the first Makefile. Also I'd like to print out filename too, by that I can tell which file has the problem

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with `find` and `awk`

```
find -type f -name "Makefile" -exec awk 'FNR==235 {print FILENAME; print}' {} +
```

This prints:

- Name of Makefile
- Line 235 of that Makefile

**Explanation:**

- `find -type f -name "Makefile"` - Recursively find all files from current working directory that are named `Makefile`
- `-exec awk 'FNR==235 {print FILENAME; print}' {} +` - For each such file found, use `awk` to print its name, and then its content at line 235.